# Testing accuracy more than training accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, auc

I am building a tuned random forest model for multiclass classification.
I'm getting the following results 
Training accuracy(AUC) :0.9921996 
Testing accuracy(AUC) :0.992237664
I saw a question related to this on this website and the common answer seems to be that the dataset must be small and your model got lucky
But in my case I have about 300k training data points and 100k testing data points
Also my classes are well balanced

```
> summary(train$Bucket)
         0   1 TO  30 121 TO 150 151 TO 180 181 TO 365   31 TO 60 366 TO 540 541 TO 730   61 TO 90 
    166034      32922       4168       4070      15268      23092       8794       6927      22559 
     730 +  91 TO 120 
     20311      11222 
> summary(test$Bucket)
         0   1 TO  30 121 TO 150 151 TO 180 181 TO 365   31 TO 60 366 TO 540 541 TO 730   61 TO 90 
     55344      10974       1389       1356       5090       7698       2932       2309       7520 
     730 +  91 TO 120 
      6770       3741
```

Is it possible for a model to fit this well on a large testing data? Please answer if I can do something to cross verify that my model is indeed fitting really well.

My complete code

```
split = sample.split(Book2$Bucket,SplitRatio =0.75)
train = subset(Book2,split==T)
test = subset(Book2,split==F)
traintask <- makeClassifTask(data = train,target = "Bucket")
rf <- makeLearner("classif.randomForest")

params <- makeParamSet(makeIntegerParam("mtry",lower = 2,upper = 10),makeIntegerParam("nodesize",lower = 10,upper = 50)) 

#set validation strategy 
rdesc <- makeResampleDesc("CV",iters=5L) 

#set optimization technique 
ctrl <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 5L)

#start tuning 

tune <- tuneParams(learner = rf ,task = traintask ,resampling = rdesc ,measures = list(acc) ,par.set = params ,control = ctrl ,show.info = T) 

rf.tree <- setHyperPars(rf, par.vals = tune$x)
tune$y

r<- train(rf.tree, traintask)
getLearnerModel(r)

testtask <- makeClassifTask(data = test,target = "Bucket")

rfpred <- predict(r, testtask)
performance(rfpred, measures = list(mmce, acc))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is of order 1e-4, nothing is wrong, it is a regular, statistical error (variance of the result). Nothing to worry about. This literally means that a difference is about 0.0001 * 100,000 = 10 samples ... 10 samples out of 100k.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question offtopic to this one. I'd really appreciate if you can help. I wanted to know if it is a good practice to manipulate test data along with training data. By manipulating I mean removing outliers or modifying factor levels with rare occurances, Stuff like that

Comment: @DhruvMahajan No it is not a good practice. You should preprocess the train set and apply it to the test set. For example, if you are using [sklearn scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html), you would fit the scaler on the training set, and then transform the test set separately.